# Как корректно вывести в JSON из таблицы Excel

Tags: python, json, pandas, excel

Задача состоит в парсинге таблицы Excel. В этой таблице есть колонки, в которых ячейки состоят из букв на русском языке. При выводе в JSON - \u0418\u041c. Как корректно отобразить?

```
df = pd.read_excel('ВПР+доработка.xlsx') # открытие

with open('output1.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(json_data) # запись
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать использовать параметр `ensure_ascii`:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# Открытие таблицы Excel
df = pd.read_excel('ВПР+доработка.xlsx')

# Преобразование таблицы в JSON
json_data = df.to_json(orient='records', force_ascii=False)

# Запись JSON в файл
with open('output1.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(json_data)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: если это в действительности решило вашу проблему, я бы был благодарен если бы вы отметили мой ответ как верный(галочка слева от ответа)